# How to create signed apk from Create React Native App not React Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I used following steps for creating **create react native** app

Step 1: install globally react native using this command in cmd: "**npm i -g create-react-native-app**".

Step 2: Create project using this command : "**create-react-native-app my-project**".

Step 3: for run go to project directory using this command: "**cd my-project**".

Step 4: using this command we can run application "**npm start**".

for more details use this link:
    https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

*Note: 
**React Native** and **Create React Native** has different architecture.

In **Create React Native** there is no **Android** and **ios** folder*

I have created apk from expo but this is not signed apk.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how it works with CRNA but since it's based on Expo, according to [this page](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps):

after the set up you have to run `exp build:android` or `exp build:ios`

Answer (score 0):

You can run `npm run eject` in console - beware that it is permanent action, but your ios and android folders will appear. Then, there you will find project files, that you can open with XCode/Android Studio and create signed builds from there.  Otherwise you can check here [Deployment and Sharing app](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/react-native-scripts/template/README.md#sharing-and-deployment). As you can see : "If you want to build and deploy your app yourself, you'll need to eject from CRNA and use Xcode and Android Studio."

Comment: There is drawback of eject command: you can see:   

https://medium.com/@tuchk4/why-i-love-create-react-app-e63b1be689a3

Comment: This is a one-way operation. Once you eject, you can’t go back! And I never run eject at my application because:

Comment: @JitenSuthar this is react native app, not react one. I'll provide alternative in my answer though.

Comment: Can is it possible to build apk without ios and android  folder appear?

Comment: I personally, prefer to eject in order to configure android and ios projects for production - for example - build settings, app icons, launch screen, etc. Otherwise `exp build` command will work.